# Rails - User::ROLES constant is causing error for invalid form submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a constant ROLES in my user model.  It contains an array of strings, one for each user role.

In my User controller #new action, I'm creating an instant variable:

```
@roles = User::ROLES
```

Which is used to populate a select input on the user _form.html.erb

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :role %>
    <%= f.select :role, @roles, {}, { class: 'form-control' } %>
  </div>
```

It works great when the submitted form is valid, but when it's invalid I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
```

And the error page highlights this line:

```
<%= f.select :role, @roles, {}, { class: 'form-control' } %>
```

Any idea what's going on?  Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that when you submit the form and it fails validation you are rendering from the `create` action rather than the `new` action. So, you are rendering the `new` template but without having called the code in `new` which sets up `@roles`.

If you also add `@roles = User::ROLES` to the create action, perhaps when you know that validation has failed, it will solve the problem.

Comment: Perfect!  I added @roles = User::ROLES to my create and update actions, and it fixed the problem.  Thanks!